# Pancakeswap Error when trying to swap token to BNB using Web3.js and Python

Tags: web3js, python, bsc, pancakeswap

I have written a Swap in python using web3.js. I can't seem to get it to work when I try to buy BNB for tokens. The transaction is created, but the Pancakeswap router gives me the following error:
Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'
Transaction ID: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x250067702884ddf0b69de814ab2e8f31aa6e873b8834289a52340788f1f46ad5

Earlier issues with this problem seem to have been with not calling functions.approve before the transaction, but I think I am doing that in the code with my contract.functions.approve(buytoken_address, 5000000000) ? Or am I doing it the wrong way somehow?

All best,
Björn

```
router_address = web3.toChecksumAddress("0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E")
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=router_address, abi=PancakeABI)
your_wallet_address = web3.toChecksumAddress('0x0cc76CDA9fF1103bd58383598d62a4224b4A25C8')


def starttransactionwithtoken():
    contract = web3.eth.contract(address=router_address, abi=PancakeABI)
    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(your_wallet_address)
    buying_this_token = web3.toChecksumAddress(0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c)
    spending_this_token = web3.toChecksumAddress(0xd2de3fd31b5c9E1557cf329032615a2870A29cCD)
    contract.functions.approve('0xd2de3fd31b5c9E1557cf329032615a2870A29cCD', 500000000)
    contract.functions.allowance('0x0cc76CDA9fF1103bd58383598d62a4224b4A25C8', '0xd2de3fd31b5c9E1557cf329032615a2870A29cCD')



    estimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({'nonce': '0x0cc76CDA9fF1103bd58383598d62a4224b4A25C8', 'to':'0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c', 'from': '0x4da753b2eb74F9FBea9f15eC311F411FbC8cC308', 'value': 50})
    print("Gas estimate is: ", estimate)

    pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        500000000, 0,
        [spending_this_token,buying_this_token],
        your_wallet_address,
        (int(time.time()) + 1000000)
        ).buildTransaction({
        'from': your_wallet_address,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('20','gwei'),
        'gasLimit': estimate,
        'nonce': nonce,
        })
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=private)
    tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    print(web3.toHex(tx_token))
```

UPDATE: updated the code to better show the functions involved. I have also added estimateGas, which still doesn't solve the problem.
UPDATE2: I've added a line for checking allowance.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to [approve the token allowance](https://tokenallowance.io/). Read the [EIP-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard to make sure you understand how ERC-20/ BEP-20 tokens work under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! As far as I can see, I have a line with contract.functions.approve to approve a new allowance. I've added a line for checking the allowance, as per the link you sent me. Do not think this is the issue though. Still getting the same error, anyway. Or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Oh wait, I missed that. The allowance bit looks all right, then. Just make sure that "0xd2de3fd31b5c9E1557cf329032615a2870A29cCD" is the router/ contract you're sending the tokens to.